# Where can Null Byte Injection affect my PHP web app in a realistic setting?

Tags: php, security

I've just read the PHP section on
http://projects.webappsec.org/Null-Byte-Injection.

The example it provides is pretty dumb - I mean, why would you *ever* want to include a file based on an outside param without checking it first (for directory traversal attacks, for one)?

So, if following standard PHP security practices, such as

- encoding user entered data on display
- validating user entered stuff that works with files
- preventing CRSF
- not running uploads via something that executes PHP
- etc

Can anyone provide a real life example or a common mistake of PHP developers where this problem can occur?

Thanks

### Upate

I'm trying to make something break, and this what I have [tried](http://ideone.com/84UuH).

```
// $filename is from public
$filename = "some_file\0_that_is_bad.jpg";

$ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

var_dump($filename, $ext);
```

Which outputs

```
string(26) "some_file�_that_is_bad.jpg"
string(3) "jpg"
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe that part of the fun with Null byte injection is that simple validation may not be good enough to catch them

e.g. the string "password.txt\0blah.jpg" actually ends with ".jpg" as far as the scripting language is concerned .. but when passed to a C based function ( such as many system functions) it gets truncated to "password.txt"

This means that a simple check like this may not be safe. (this is just pseudocode, not PHP)

```
 if ( filename.endswith(".jpg") ) { some_c_function(filename); }
```

Instead you may have to do

```
 filename = break_at_null(filename);
 if ( filename.endswith(".jpg") ) { some_c_function(filename); }
```

Now it doesn't really matter what that c function is .. the examples in the cited article may have need file reading functions, but it could just as well be database accesses, system calls, etc.

Comment: What functions are not safe (i.e. just wrapped C functions)? I guess `strlen()`, `strcmp()`, etc, but is there a definite list? Cheers.

Comment: Not that I know of (but I'm new to this area too). Though I suspect it will depend on your PHP version and probably your OS too.

Comment: On my version of php (5.2.12 on OS X) some of the functions I thought might fail are fine: printf, sprintf, strlen.